# how and where to save the habtm relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkboxlist

I am a beginner in rails.
I have a Subject table (attribute: subject_name) and a Semester table (attribute: semester_no).
a subject can be assigned to different semesters and a semester can have many subjects. so, there must be a many-to-many relation. 
i've created a semesters_subjects table (attribute: semester_id, subject_id). 
i need a form for the admin to assign the subjects to different semesters. From that form i need to save the subjects belongs to the semesters. how can i do that?
where i save my these relations?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the rails guide on HABTM relationships:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

If you set up a join model/table named semesters_subjects and add the code according to the guide to your models the join records will be created automatically using the right syntax.

For example to associate a subject with a semester

```
semester.subjects.push(subject)
```

Or to create a subject associated with the semester

```
semester.create_subject(attributes)
```

I'd also read up on ActiveRecord basics here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html